# Can't set properties on child class after async calling constructor of base class. NodeJS v8.2.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, async-await, es6-promise

Could you please help to understand what can be wrong while using promises in callback on parent class and then trying to set properties on child class?

I'm using nodejs v8.2.1

Here is example of base class:

```
class CGLBase extends CAuthClient
{
    constructor(req, res)
    {   
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            super(req, res, (authClient) => {
                this.setAuthClient(authClient);
                resolve(this);
            });
        });
    }

    setAuthClient(authClient)
    {
       //setting authClient (this.auth will contain property)
    }
}
```

And here example of child class:

```
class СSheet extends CGLBase
{
    constructor(document, urlRequest, urlResponse) 
    {
        super(urlRequest, urlResponse);      

        this.document = document;
        this.someAnotherProp = "some property";
        //etc.. 
    }

    someFunc()
    {
       //using this.document and this.auth
    }
 }
```

After that I'm creating instance of СSheet and trying to set properties:

```
var document = { ... }; //here I create object

(async () => {
    var docSheet = await new СSheet (document, req, res);
    docSheet.someFunc();

    console.log(docSheet.auth);  //return correct property
    console.log(docSheet.document); //return undefined. why...
})();
```

So, I don't understand why property **this.document** wasn't set. I see only **this.auth** that was set in the async callback. All properties **except this.auth** are **undefined**.

I will be very grateful for advice or help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `this` is not available in ES6 constructors until *after* the call to `super`. When your callback arrow function is defined, `this` is still `undefined`. Also, I'm not sure why you would need to create an async constructor. It seems like this would be better implemented as an async static factory method.

Comment: Since when should constructors return promises?

Comment: Important read: [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572)

Comment: It's generally bad practice to have asynchronous  constructors. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why property this.document wasn't set. I see only this.auth that was set in the async callback.

Your `CSheet` constructor did set the `document` and `someAnotherProp` properties on the *promise* returned by `super()`. `await`ing the `new CSheet` gives you the `CAuthClient` instance that the promise was resolved with, and which does not have the properties.

You *could* work around that by using

```
class СSheet extends CGLBase {
    constructor(document, urlRequest, urlResponse) {
        return super(urlRequest, urlResponse).then(instance => {
            instance.document = document;
            instance.someAnotherProp = "some property";
            // …
            return instance;
        });
    }
    …
}
```

but you [really absolutely never *should* do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572). This of course is the fault of `CAuthClient` taking an asynchronous callback. Fix that class and all its children to do the asynchronous creation of `authClient` in a static helper method, and only pass plain values into the constructor.