# Not a Constructor with async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I am trying to make a constructor function in JavaScript, and this constructor should be asynchronous, cause I am using Phantom JS module to scrape the data,so that's why I have to use asynchronous function to scrap data through Phantom JS with Node JS.

Below is my code,

```js
const phantom = require('phantom');
async function InitScrap() {

  var MAIN_URL = "https://www.google.com/",
      //Phantom JS Variables
      instance = await phantom.create(),
      page = await instance.createPage();


  // Load the Basic Page First      
  this.loadPage = async function() {
    console.log("Loading Please wait...");
    var status = await page.open(MAIN_URL);
    if (status == "success") {
      page.render("new.png");
      console.log("Site has been loaded");
    }
  }

}

var s = new InitScrap();
s.loadPage()

// module.exports = InitScrap();
```

> But when I run this code it says, `InitScrap()` is not a constructor, am I missing something ?

Comment: Because it's a function?

Comment: `async` functions cannot be constructors

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS) is how we make constructor functions @Ric

Comment: [A constructor should not do anything asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructor functions are functions that return an Object of the type defined in the function, like this "Person" class from MDN you cited:

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.greeting = function() {
    alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name + '.');
  };
}
```

It returns an Object with a name and a greeting function when used with the `new` keyword.

When you use the `async` keyword, you can `await` Promises in the function but it also converts that function into a promise generator, meaning it will return a Promise, not an Object, that's why it can't be a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Refer here for more details: [Async/Await Class Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor)

But to summarize,

`async` functions cannot be constructors.

```
function func(){
    this.foo = 'bar'
}

const f = new func();
console.log(f.foo);
```

This will work but `async function func() { .. }` will not work