# Returning a query result from a class's method

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I don’t know if this is possible, since i've do my best and still can’t resolve it here's my code

```
class account {
        constructor(id){
            this.id = id;
            this.solde = this.getSolde();
        }
     
        async getSolde(){
            const result = await con.query('SELECT solde FROM account WHERE id = ?', [this.id])
            return result[0];
        }
    }
```

When I call getSolde() I’ve either undefined or pending promise with different methods I've tried before, like getter, callback, none seems to work for me, can anyone help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor/43433773

Answer (score 0):

`getSolde()` is async so you need to await it. But you can't do that inside the constructor because it needs to be marked as async, which can't be done.

Since you are returning the value, it should be returned if you just add a `then` on the promise:

```
constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.getSolde().then(result => this.solde = result);
}
```

Comment: i'm getting promise undefined

Comment: In `getSolde`, can you console.log(result) to confirm that you actually have a result which is an array and the result you want is at index 0.

Comment: in getSolde i'm getting Promise { <pending> }

Comment: now i managed to get result on console, with < const account = new acount(id); account.getSolde().then(result =>console.log(result)); but i can't assignt result to any variable, i can only console.log inside then method

Comment: @user9224596 you can do `account.getSolde().then(result => account.solde = result);` Or if you want to log out the result as well, you can put it inside a block: `account.getSolde().then(result => {console.log(result); result = account.solde;});`

Comment: how could I call account.solde if this isn't defined inside constructor ?

Comment: Maybe this will help you understand: `const a = new account(1);
a.getSolde().then(result => a.solde = result).then(_ => console.log(a.solde));`

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to avoid asynchronous actions inside your constructor. It would be better to instantiate the class with using id and then externally call `getSolde()`:

```
const account = new account(id: 1);
await account.getSolde();
```

Comment: i thought it's not possible to wait outside an async function, anyway i've tried and isn't working

Comment: await account.getSolde()
                ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Well, apparently you need to have an async function in order to await another function. If possible, please provide your source code, so we can guide you want to change.