# How to use fetch in OOP?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, fetch

I want to start learning OOP and using fetch to GET information. But I am struggling at communicating between Classes. I am unable to GET the information into another Class for further processing.

## My Code

`Fetch.js`

```js
class Fetch  {
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    async fetchData(path) {
        const res =  await fetch(path)
        const { status } = res;
        if (status <  200  || status >=  300) {
            return  console.log("Oh-Oh! Seite konnte nicht gefunden werden: " + status)
        }
        this.data = res.text();
    }
}

export  default Fetch;
```

`Day08.js`

```js
1  | import Fetch from "./Fetch.js";
2  | 
3  | class Day08 extends Fetch  {
4  |    constructor() {
5  |        super(data);
6  |        this.doSomething();
7  |    }
8  | 
9  |   doSomething() {
10 |    console.log(this.data)
11 |    }
12 | }
13 | 
14 | new Day08();
```

Inside my Console, I then get, that `data is not defined` in Day08 on line 6.

### Question

So the question I have is, how can I use the data I got from the fetch?
I also tried writing my `doSomething()` differently, like so:

```js
doSomething() {
    const fetching =  new  Fetch.fetchData("./Inputs/08-data.txt");
    console.log(fetching)
}
```

But then I also get that data is not defined.
I don't know how to get the information and use it in a different class, I tried to look around online for an answer, but couldn't find one.
The input for fetching changes every time, to get different data. This is why I am trying to avoid making my Fetch Class with a static return.
If anyone could help me out with this, that would be great.

Comment: Modelling `fetch` as a class has rather big inherent problems. OOP is not just having classes, it's about modelling stuff *through* classes. What does the `Fetch` class even do? It calls `fetch` and does some handling. It's really no different from `fetch.then(/* ... */)` but it's less flexible as you've insulated the promise, which makes the class rather hard to use. A better design would be to allow adding more code that would handle the resolved promise. But that's the same as `.then`. You can expose the promise instead but then, why have a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to use the data in other classes that you fetch from the `Fetch` class than since the `fetchData` call is async, all of the code that will use the data must be called after the async call is finished in asynchronous manner.

```js
class Fetch {
  async fetchData(path) {
    const res = await fetch(path)

    const {
      status
    } = res;

    if (status < 200 || status >= 300) {
      return console.log("Oh-Oh! Seite konnte nicht gefunden werden: " + status)
    }

    this.data = await res.text();
  }
}

class Day08 extends Fetch {
  constructor(path) {
    super()
    this.path = path;
  }

  async init() {
    await this.fetchData(this.path);
  }

  doSomething() {
    console.log('Something', this.data)
  }

  doSomethingElse() {
    console.log('Else ', this.data)
  }
}

const day = new Day08('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')

day.init().then(() => {
  day.doSomething();
  day.doSomethingElse();
})
```

Comment: This worked out great. Do you know of a way where I don't need to use the last lines of code? Like calling the function in the constructor?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor

Answer (score 0):

Seems like problem is constructor of Day08 must have **data** param

```
constructor(data) {
   super(data);
   this.doSomething();
}
```