# Why is JavaScript not recognizing my function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, error-handling, typeerror

I am creating a class in JavaScript, in that class I created a few functions however only the constructor seems to work. What am I missing because I did another class in the same exact format and it worked perfectly.

```
class Articles {
    constructor(dbName = ':memory:') {
        return // Some async function  
            return this
        })()
    }
    async all() {
        //another async function
        }
        return articles
    }
    async add(data) {
        console.log('ADD')
        console.log(data)
        return true
    }
    async close() {
        await this.db.close
    }
}
export default Articles
```

I have taken out the parts that I dont think are necessary just so that its easier to read.
The issue I have is with the last two functions add and close.
The class exports fine.
[image: This is the type error that I keep getting]

Here is the function that I run it in

```
router.post('/add', async ctx => {
    const a = await new Articles(dbName)
    try{
        ctx.request.body.account = ctx.session.userid
        }
        await new Articles(dbName).add(ctx.request.body) //Here is the add function
        return ctx.redirect('/?msg=new article added')
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
        await ctx.render('error', ctx.hbs)
    } finally {
        new Articles(dbName).close() //Here is the close function
    }
})
```

Comment: The constructor isn't asynchronous, I don't think you can use `await new Articles`

Comment: Why do you keep calling `new Articles(dbName)` instead of using the `a` variable?

Comment: `await this.db.close` should be `await this.db.close()`

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor) is relevant.

Comment: No it was I apologize I was outside and my computer died

Comment: I am currently trying all of your suggestions

Comment: The reason I wasn't using the a variable is because I thought it was the issue. I was doubting myself that much