# How to await in constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I try to use await in class constructor but failed, here are my trys:

```
export class TheHistory {
  constructor(private readonly db: EntityManager){
        //try1: too many levels !!! try use await
        mydb.insert(god).then(() => {
          mydb.insert(human).then(() => {
            mydb.insert(city).then(() => {
              //.....
            })
          })
        })

        //try2: ERROR -- 'await'expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules
        await mydb.insert(god)
        await mydb.insert(human)
        await mydb.insert(city)
  }
}
```

Comment: Create a new async method, move your code to that, and then call that method from your constructor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50885340/9418800 I think this is what you need

Comment: You shouldn't do anything asynchronous in your constructor, because you can't handle errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `await` inside an `async` function, so either extract the code to an `async` method or use a immediately-invoked async function expression.

```js
constructor(private readonly db: EntityManager){
    (async()=>{
        await mydb.insert(god)
        await mydb.insert(human)
        await mydb.insert(city)
    })();
}
```

Comment: One thing to note, if anything in the constructor relies upon data returned by an `async` call, that code must also be inside the immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE). Attempting to pass a value outside the IIFE will return a promise, continuing the initial problem.

Answer (score -2):

Try call to constructor from outside

```
async function foo () {
    var myObj = await mydb.insert(god);
}
```