# Fetch returns undefined data sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, function, fetch-api

I'm using fetch to get information, sometimes it shows everything well, sometimes if shows nothing everything is undefined, and sometimes it shows some data well with some data as undefined. the images shows my issue:

[image]

and that's my code:

```
// fetch the movies from API

class Movie {

  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.load();
  }
  finalize(json) {
    this.name = json.original_title;
    this.img = json.poster_path;
    this.link = name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s/ ]/g, "");
    var MyArray = {
      'name': `${this.name}`,
      'img': `${this.img}`,
      'link': `/movies/${this.link}.html`
    }
    console.log(MyArray)
  }

  load() {
    fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.id}?api_key=a913ee104db6b795d20852a9ed989036`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.finalize(json)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }

}

// The array of movies

const MyMovies = [
  new Movie(238),
  new Movie(899082),
  new Movie(899),
]

// show the movies in the page

function LoadMovies() {
  var table = document.querySelector('#movies')
  for (var i = 0; i < MyMovies.length; i++) {
    var item = MyMovies[i];
    var row = `<img id="img" src="${'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/' + item.img}" alt="${item.name}" class="thumb" onclick="location.href='${"movies/" + item.link + ".html"}'">`
    table.innerHTML += row
  }
}
```

Comment: Really hard to say - what is the response of the http request? What does the data look like? I'd start there

Comment: `new Movie()` doesn't wait for the async fetch to complete. I don't think there's a way to wait for an asynchronous class constructor. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor

Comment: @Tom the data look like this : ```{
      'name': `${this.name}`,
      'img': `${this.img}`,
      'link': `/movies/${this.link}`}```

Comment: @Barmar so how can i fix that, can you answer with the solution please ?

Comment: @jabaa can you answer by the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait until all movies are initialized:

```js
// fetch the movies from api

class Movie {

  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.isInitialized = this.load();
  }
  finalize(json) {
    this.name = json.original_title;
    this.img = json.poster_path;
    this.link = name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s/ ]/g, "");
    var MyArray = {
      'name': `${this.name}`,
      'img': `${this.img}`,
      'link': `/movies/${this.link}.html`
    }
    console.log(MyArray)
  }

  load() {
    return fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.id}?api_key=a913ee104db6b795d20852a9ed989036`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.finalize(json)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }

}

// The array of movies

const MyMovies = [
  new Movie(238),
  new Movie(899082),
  new Movie(899),
]

// show the movies in the page

async function LoadMovies() {
  var table = document.querySelector('#movies');
  await Promise.all(MyMovies.map(movie => movie.isInitialized));
  for (var i = 0; i < MyMovies.length; i++) {
    var item = MyMovies[i];
    var row = `<img id="img" src="${'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/' + item.img}" alt="${item.name}" class="thumb" onclick="location.href='${"movies/" + item.link + ".html"}'">`
    table.innerHTML += row
  }
}

LoadMovies();
```

```html
<table id="movies">

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor doesn't wait for the fetch to complete, so you're trying to use all the `Movie` objects before the information has been fetched. There's no way to await a class constructor, because it always returns a class instance, not a promise (see [Async/Await Class Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor)).

Instead of calling `this.load()` in the constructor, do it in the loop.

```js
class Movie {

  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  finalize(json) {
    this.name = json.original_title;
    this.img = json.poster_path;
    this.link = name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s/ ]/g, "");
    var MyArray = {
      'name': `${this.name}`,
      'img': `${this.img}`,
      'link': `/movies/${this.link}.html`
    }
    console.log(MyArray)
  }

  load() {
    fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.id}?api_key=a913ee104db6b795d20852a9ed989036`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.finalize(json)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }

}

// The array of movies

const MyMovies = [
  new Movie(238),
  new Movie(899082),
  new Movie(899),
]

// show the movies in the page

async function LoadMovies() {
  var table = document.querySelector('#movies')
  for (var i = 0; i < MyMovies.length; i++) {
    var item = MyMovies[i];
    await item.load();
    var row = `<img id="img" src="${'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/' + item.img}" alt="${item.name}" class="thumb" onclick="location.href='${"movies/" + item.link + ".html"}'">`
    table.innerHTML += row
  }
}
```