# Javascript why Product2 is never called contrary to Product1

Tags: javascript

I'm experimenting with javascript function as object and async. Why Product2 below is never called ?

```js
function Product(title) {
  this.title = title;
  this.getInfo = function() {
    return this.title;
  }
  return this;
}

async function Product2(title) {
  this.title = title;
  this.getInfo = function() {
    return this.title;
  }
  console.log(this.title)
  return this;
}

async function main() {
  console.log("start")


  var product = new Product("car");
  console.log(product.getInfo());

  var product2 = await new Product2("car 2");
  console.log(product2.getInfo());

  console.log("end")
}

main();
```

Comment: I don't think constructor functions can be async, or at least I don't get the purpose of them. See similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor

Comment: `new` doesn't make sense with an async function. Yet it is weird that it apparently just hangs.

Comment: @VLAZ firefox throws a "Product2 is not a constructor" error.

Comment: @evolutionxbox ok, that makes sense now. I just wasn't looking at the browser console, I copied the snippet and ran it. That error doesn't show up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every function is a constructor. Some quotes from the ECMAScript specification clarify this:

[Essential Internal Methods](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2021/#table-essential-internal-methods)

> A function object is an object that supports the `[[Call]]` internal method. A constructor is an object that supports the `[[Construct]]` internal method. [...] A function object is not necessarily a constructor and such non-constructor function objects do not have a `[[Construct]]` internal method.

Async functions are functions that are in the non-constructor category:

[CreateDynamicFunction](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2021/#sec-createdynamicfunction):

> NOTE: Functions whose *kind* is `async` are not constructible and do not have a `[[Construct]]` internal method or a `"prototype"` property.

And:

[AsyncFunction Instances](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2021/#sec-async-function-instances):

> AsyncFunction instances are not constructors and do not have a `[[Construct]]` internal method. AsyncFunction instances do not have a `prototype` property as they are not constructible.

Other examples of functions that cannot be constructors:

[Function Instances - prototype](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2021/#sec-function-instances-prototype):

> Function objects created using `Function.prototype.bind`, or by evaluating a *MethodDefinition* (that is not a *GeneratorMethod* or *AsyncGeneratorMethod*) or an *ArrowFunction* do not have a `"prototype"` property.

Your example code actually runs into an exception because of the above reasons:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Product2 is not a constructor

(for some reason this exception is not logged in the Stack Snippet, but a browser will show it in their console)

Comment: "*for some reason this exception is not logged in the Stack Snippet*" it's because it fails in a promise and the Stack Snippets don't show async failures.

Comment: Would be good if Stack Snippets were improved to output such uncaught exceptions.

Comment: Would be, I agree. IIRC, it's actually an open source project but I can't remember where to find it. It might accept pull requests.

Answer (score 1):

```
async function Product2(title)
```

As this is async, There should be an uncaught TypeError when you are doing this:

```
var product2 = await new Product2("car 2");
```

cause `Product2` is not a constructor anymore.

A function marked with async will return a promise.

A constructor on the other hand returns the object it is constructing. Thus we have a situation where you want to both return an object and a promise: an impossible situation.

Answer (score -1):

*new Product2* will create an instance of an object of *product2*

You cannot use await and new keyword together.

Comment: "*new Product2 will create an instance of an object of product2*" no, it will not since you cannot call an async function with `new`. "*You cannot use await and new keyword together.*" this is also wrong. It *is* syntactically valid code. Whether it makes sense logically is a different matter, however, a function called with `new` *can* return a promise, thus `await new foo()` can be valid code: https://jsbin.com/yevuwerile/edit?js,console