# Promise.all to fetch JSON Datas is Empty

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

In my code, I am trying to fetch data from two JSON files and return them as an array. I did the solution below but it didn't work. What should I do to log those arrays on to the console and achieve what I want?

TS:

```
  requests = [
    'data/products.json',
    'data/categories.json',
  ];

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    const x = Promise.all(this.requests.map((url) => fetch(url))).then(
      async (res) => Promise.all(res.map(async (data) => await data.json()))
    );
    console.log(x);
  }
```

Comment: I think you've overcomplicated it ... it's hard to read that code

Comment: i didn't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: you're using `async` needlessly for a start, and where you do have an await, there really is no need

Comment: Aren't you logging a Promise in this case? The result of Promise.all(...).then(...) is a Promise.

Comment: [You can’t have an async constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43431550/989920), so you’ll not be able to log x like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're over complicating the code with all those pointless `async`

The issue is, that x is a Promise ... an unresolved Promise at the time you console.log it

try the following instead

```
requests = [
    'data/products.json',
    'data/categories.json',
];

constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    const makeRequest = (url) => fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
    
    Promise.all(this.requests.map(this.makeRequest))
    .then(x => console.log(x));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `Promise.all` is "empty" (technically a `Promise`) because it hasn't resolved by the time you are logging. You should `await` it or capture the result at `.then`.

I would rewrite that as `const x = await Promise.all(...)` outside of a constructor in a method or go with `Promise.all(...).then(...)`.

Comment: x would actually be a Promise, not "empty"

Comment: when i add await at the beginning, I get an error of `'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.(1308)`

Comment: Yeah, it would be a promise. I was thinking there was something weird in his environment as he didn't specify where he is running.

Comment: If it's allowed, you would need `async constructor`. That's why I had the second paragraph.

Comment: If that's not legal, then you would have to capture the result at `.then`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor

Comment: Yeah, it looks like `async constructor` isn't a thing by definition so you would have to find another way.