# Initializing empty field and assigning field in same constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor

I have a class that manages access to a football API. The class has a field called `season` which represents the current season of play as a string. Tu update this I have a method to re-assign the `season`-field, which is my `getCurrentSeason()`-method.

I need access to `season`, but would also like to set the value of `season` in the constructor to have a value as soon as I initialize my `ApiManager`. I saw it was possible to call `this.getCurrentSeason()` from a similar piece of code, but `season` remains an empty string in my case.

Through debugging, I can see that the API call comes through and gives access to the necessary information. I was thinking of just returning the season in `getCurrentSeason()` so I could call `this.season = getCurrentSeason()` in the constructor instead, but I would still like to be able to call the method elsewhere to update the fields of my `ApiManager`, so I would like to avoid this approach.

Code below. Any help is appreciated.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

export class ApiManager {
    constructor() {
        this.season = '';
        this.options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              ... // API key removed
            }
          };
        this.getCurrentSeason();
    }

    async getCurrentSeason() {
        const url = 'https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/leagues?id=39&current=true';
        try {
            let response = await fetch(url, this.options);
            let json = await response.json();
            this.season = json['response'][0]['seasons'][0]['year'];
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Async/Await Class Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to building an async constructor in which case the answer to your question is the following:

This can **never** work.

You can check out the brilliant answer from @slebetman here: [Async/Await Class Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is helpful and a good link, but more of a comment than an answer, IMO.

Comment: I get the idea behind it, but can't quite think of a solution based on that. Maybe it will come to me. Thanks either way!