# How to check if model is already created in mongoose without await

Tags: javascript, mongoose, async-await

I have to define in a constructor which is not async a mongoose model. But I want to check first if the model already exists. How can I do this without await?

```
class Some {
    constructor()
        this.dbClient.getConnection().model(eventModel.DB_MODEL_NAME, eventModel.DB_MODEL_SCHEMA)
}
```

Comment: You cannot use an asynchronous command in a constructor: See [Async/Await Class Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43431550/215552)

Comment: Ok, @HereticMonkey, what about if I dont check if the model/collection already exists, but I just create it every time as in the code in my question? Will this cause any troubles? 

Is there some functionality, when we use mongoose.model('name', Schema) - to first check if exists and if not, then to create it? I tried to see in the documentation and the code itself, but i didnt.