# How to have a run time config file for aurelia app built with webpacks 4

Tags: webpack-4, aurelia

I have a application built with  aurelia and bundled with webpacks. I have a variables in a typescript file. When i do a producation build, I just want to change those variables when I deploy at various servers.
Example apiRoot= http://10.10.0.1/RESTSERVICES/---> when deployed at one server
when deployed at another server I what apiRoot do be different.
But I don't want to build the code multiple times to deploy at various locations.

For this reason I'm looking a run time config file for aurelia application built with webpacks. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is potentially similar to the Q here [Aureliajs Waiting For Data on App Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55220012/aureliajs-waiting-for-data-on-app-constructor/55309252).

In that question, I gave suggestion on how to do it in different ways, which is copy-pasted below:

Aurelia provides many ways to handle asynchronous flow. If your custom element is a routed component, then you can leverage `activate` lifecycle to return a promise and initialize the http service asynchronously.

Otherwise, you can use `CompositionTransaction` to halt the process further, before you are done with initialization. You can see a preliminary example at https://tungphamblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/15/aurelia-customelement-async/

You can also leverage async nature of `configure` function in bootstrapping an Aurelia application to do initialization there:

```js
export function configure(aurelia) {
  ...
  await aurelia.container.get(HttpServiceInitializer).initialize();
}
```